# Eclipse -> Java -> GUI Builder -> Can't get my UI to show properly in design mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gui-builder

I am new to Java and Eclipse.

Somehow, my ui is not showing up the right way. Instead of seeing my frame, with the x to close at the top right, etc, and all the controls, I see a frame with no border.

See here: http://s7.postimg.org/miprf5ul7/Noooooooooooo.png

Here's my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/74mltgsxcs9vjnf/PDF%20Monster.zip

I've spent countless hours working on this.
Please help me restore my UI, I'm desperate.

Thank you,

Comment: I haven't seen your code but make sure you haven't set your `JFrame` to be undecorated with: `frame.setUndecorated(true)`

Comment: it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at ui.UI_Pdf_Monster_Main.main(UI_Pdf_Monster_Main.java:135)

Comment: The code starts at that line like    public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     UI_Pdf_Monster_Main window = new UI_Pdf_Monster_Main();
     window.frmPdfImpositionMonster.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you can't view your ui the right way look at the code to see if there's red blocks in the right side. This indicates errors that may cause this.

In my case I had deleted a semicolon by accident somewhere...

If you fix the errors, it should be fine.
Also, you can simply try to comment out the errors to see if you can see the ui.